# Reformat a JSON object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON object which I want to reformat, here's what I mean...

JSON object...

```
{
"query":"de mar",
"suggestions":[
    "Any Location",
    "Camp De Mar, Majorca, SPAIN",
    "L'amettla De Mar, Costa Dorada, SPAIN",
    "Lloret De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",
    "Malgrat De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",
    "Pineda De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",
    "Roquetas De Mar, Costa De Almeria, SPAIN",
    "Tossa De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN"
],
"data":[
    "",
    "DestinationResort|Camp De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|L'Amettla De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Lloret De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Malgrat De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Pineda De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Roquetas De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Tossa De Mar"
]
}
```

I want to turn this into the following...

```
{
"destinations": [
    "": "Any Location",
    "DestinationResort|Camp De Mar": "Camp De Mar, Majorca, SPAIN",
    // etc etc
]
}
```

At the moment I have the following (pathetic use of jquery coding)...

```
$("#search").on("input", function() {
  $.getJSON( "http://holidays.allinclusive.co.uk/external/destinations.ashx?query=" + $("#search").val() )
  .done(function(data) {
    var myObject = ['destinations'];
    $.each(data.suggestions, function (index, elem) {
      myObject['destinations'] = {[data.data[index]] : [elem] };
    });
  })
});
```

What I am really trying to do is use this with autocomplete() or bootstrap's typeahead() to populate an input but I think this is my next step.

Please can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm, are `suggestions:[]` & `data:[]` a 1:1 match? Each line references the respective line in the other object?

Comment: Hm, I may have misread this the first time. Is `destinations` in the result object supposed to be an array of objects or an object with key-value pairs? My answer assumes the former, but figured I'd check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close, but there are a few issues with the creation of your new objects.

```
var myObject = ['destinations'];
```

This creates an array with a single element, the string "destinations". What you actually want is an object with a property `destinations` that is an empty array, so change it to:

```
var myObject = {
    destinations: []
};
```

The `.each()` iteration is correct, but the code for each iteration isn't. What your code is doing is taking your array `myObject`, and setting the `destinations` property (which doesn't exist in the first iteration) of that equal to the object for the current iteration; you instead want to be pushing the new object into the array. There's also a problem with the creation of the object, since you can't have dynamic keys when creating an object literal.

```
$.each(data.suggestions, function (index, elem) {
    var currentObject = {}
    currentObject[data.data[index]] = elem;
    myObject.destinations.push(currentObject);
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wzqS/)

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad start! You just need a little rearranging.

```
var myObject = {'destinations': []};
$.each(data.suggestions, function (index, elem) {
  myObject.destinations[data.data[index]] = elem;
});
```

You see, you want myObject to be a json object as you described with one 'key' known as 'destinations' which is an array. Start out with an empty array and set the indexes of it afterwards.